# Just Cause 2 pipeline Computer hacking failures

Tags: just-cause-2

I am playing Just Cause 2 on my PC via my Steam account and I am at the stage where I have to hack the pipe line computers.  I start the hack with four numbers displayed(e.g. 1 2 4 3). The hack starts, but every time it tells me that the "HACK FAILED". I have tried the hack about 20 times continuously with no success what  so ever. I am stuck as the game will not let me progress.

Comment: You are entering the numbers correctly, yes?

Comment: Are you being shot by enemy soldiers? It's possible the hacking fails because you're being hit.

Answer (score 2):

If you **enter a number incorrectly** or are **shot while entering the code**, the hack will automatically fail.

However, it could be the case that the mission is simply glitched and is unable to progress in its current state (I once had a mission where I needed to follow someone, but the place they were standing in was outside of the mission area, so I couldn't finish the mission).  If this happens, the only solution is to restart from the latest autosave.  It sucks, but the missions in this game aren't that long, so it's not too much of a pain.